# Determine whether the div is opened or closed using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am want to create a javascript function using jQuery which will close the div if div is opened and vice-versa.

For that I need to determine whether a particular div is opened or closed?

So is there any method available which satisfies my requirement?

Anything like $('div#myContainer').isOpened() ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like this?

```
if($('#myContainer').is(':visible')){
 $('#myContainer').slideToggle();
}
```

Or

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#myContainer').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        //Do something
  });
});
```

Comment: Both slideToggle() and toggle() worked. Accepting the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a custom attribute to the div that you could check with jQuery and use as a flag. You can also look at the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method

Comment: Yes Waage. I was looking for the same. Thx :-)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "opened"?

Would something like this do?

```
$('#myContainer').is(':visible')
```

Comment: HI David. Thx for your effort. It will determine whether the container is visible. toggle() will do the magic for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check if Div's css "Display" property is none
You can get css attribute by

```
var checkOpen =$('#myContainer').css('display');
```

Comment: Hey GG. I got a more feasible answer and which I have posted.